# Proxy Webserver Remote Address Header

Tags: http, proxy, http-headers, naming-conventions

I am setting up some proxy functionality, and wanted to keep things consistent with what is commonplace.

What is the typical header name for Remote Address, is it `REMOTE_ADDR`?

What happens if the browser sends a `REMOTE_ADDR` header, is it ignored or renamed?